# How to link map marker to detail view on Sencha Touch (Architect 2)

Tags: sencha-touch-2, marker, detailview

I have a map with a marker, and i want to make the marker clicktable to show some basic info.

I am new to Sencha, and I need advice what should I implemante in listener function to get the same effect as i click on list item:

for example, this is my code of maprender function

```
var lat = 37.428607;
var lng = -122.169344;


var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);


var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: gmap,
    draggable: false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    title: 'cool'
});


var contentString = 'bla bla bla';


var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});


google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      /* here comes something that will make my detail list visible with the marker details*/
});
```

and i want to make it work in the same way as my function for "itemtap" which i use in my list... something like this:

```
onMyListItemTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, options) {
this.setActiveItem('detalji');this.down('#back').show();
this.down('#detalji').setData(record.data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great example on Github for Sencha Touch 1...I believe it's called World Map. If you unzip that (the app is in one of the many folders) you can see a Google map wil multiple custom markers. This project is very useful for learning, as it not only shows custom map markers, but also popup overlays on a marker click.

I have yet to adapt it to Sencha Touch 2, but it shouldn't be too difficult...here is some example code (after multiple markers have been added):

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() 
                {
        if (!this.popup) 
                    {
          this.popup = new Ext.Panel(
                            {
            floating: true,
            modal: true,
            centered: true,
            width: 500,
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            scroll: 'vertical',
            items:[{
              xtype:'button', 
              ui:'round',
              text:'See Country Profile',
              handler:goToCountryWrapper,
              scope : this
            },
            (new countryOverlay(country)).overlayPanel
            ],
                layout: {
              type: 'auto',
              padding: '55',
              align: 'left'
            },
            dockedItems: [{
              dock: 'top',
              xtype: 'toolbar',
              title: country.title
              }],
          });
        };
        this.popup.show('pop');
      });
```

Also I think from what I understand about Sencha Touch 2, you would have to put a listener in your map controller (MyApp.map.controller file)....read up about the refs, as the refs 'finds' the marker(s) you have defined and adds a listener to the item.

If you have any progress please post your findings :-)